# Android NameValuePair: Can I store non-string data types in it?

Tags: java, android, apache, basicnamevaluepair

From the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html), we can see that it is `org.apache.http.NameValuePair`, so looking at the original [documentation given here at apache.org](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/NameValuePair.html), it has the constructor:

```
public NameValuePair(String name,
                     String value)
```

But I also want to store other data type values, like boolean and int. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a `Map` of some sort instead. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html

Comment: That's where I started, but map can store values of one data type right? I have like 10 keys with values, where keys are Strings and values are Strings, booleans, or ints. Now shall I make 10 maps each having one key-value pair, because a single map won't allow me to store values of different datatypes; so I thought about saving them in some *generic* sort of `NameValuePair` and then make an array of those `NameValuePair`. @Simon

Answer (score 0):

`NameValuePair` and other deprecated classes from `org.apache.http` have been removed entirely in API level `23`.

You can use `android.util.Pair`, which uses generics and lets you store any data type, e.g.:

```
// stores boolean values    
Pair<String, Boolean>> p1 = new Pair<>("key", false));

// stores int values
Pair<String, Integer>> p2 = new Pair<>("key", 1));
```